# autocompletetextview убрать клавиатуру при выборе значения из списка

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Коллеги, реализовал autocompletetextview, когда выбираю нужный параметр - нажимаю на клавиатуре "готово"(галка), но сама клавиатура не закрывается.
Как сделать закрытие клавиатуры можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программно прятать клавиатуру

```
// butCalculate - это кнопка
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(butCalculate.getWindowToken(),
        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Пример взял из [Клавиатура и аппаратные кнопки](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/keyboard.php#hide)